# Get column index based on value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

Find value in `pd.DataFrame` and get the column name or index of that value.

list of values are :

```
[['25362438,25383532 Mobile : 8691017781,8691017798',nan,nan,  nan,  nan, nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  'Mobile : 0',  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]]
```

suppose I have converted this list to pandas df. and now I want to know the column index of "Mobile : 0" then how can I know.

I used iloc but it is not working.

Comment: please add input and expected output and what you have tried so far

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan now can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a series `s`, e.g. `s = df['some_column']`, you can use Boolean indexing:

```
res = s[s == 'Mobile : 0'].index[0]
```

Deconstructing this logic:

1. `s == 'Mobile : 0'` creates a Boolean array we use to index `s`.
2. `index` attribute extracts an `index` array from the resulting series result.
3. `[0]` extracts the first element. If there are multiple matches, you can omit this to return an array.

Comment: @arun, Interesting, sorry I couldn't help. Feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50443132/edit) your question with a [mcve].